# c# entity framework throw exception but no roll back on database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a simple query which updates two tables in my database

```
public void UpdateLogins(int userId)
{
    using (var context = new storemanagerEntities())
    {
        user item = context.users.Where(x => x.id == userId).FirstOfDefault();
        item.logins += 1;
        context.SaveChanges();

        account accountItem = context.accounts.Where(x => x.userId == userId).FirstOfDefault();
        accountItem.logins += 1;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

but if I but a "throw new Exception();" between them like so

```
        context.SaveChanges();

        throw new Exception();

        account accountItem = context.accounts.Where(x => x.userId == userId).FirstOfDefault();
```

the user table is not updated but my account table has not been updated, and the database saves these changes. How can I tell my database to rollback the changes if a exception is thrown?

Thanks

Comment: Use `TransactionScope`.

Comment: so wrap a transcationscope around the "using var"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
using (TransactionScope txScope = new TransactionScope())
{    
    using (var context = new storemanagerEntities())
    {
        user item = context.users.Where(x => x.id == userId).FirstOfDefault();
        item.logins += 1;
        context.SaveChanges();

        account accountItem = context.accounts.Where(x => x.userId ==     userId).FirstOfDefault();
        accountItem.logins += 1;
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
     txScope.Complete();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Each .SaveChanges is a transaction. So you have 2.

As others pointed out enclose all in parent TransactionScope and then these 2 will became child transactions.

I.e. you'll have 1 transaction.

Or better to make just one call to .SaveChanges()

When operating with your models you should use C# references to connect models, not by ids.
Sometimes that is difficult, but that is the goal of ORMs, to let you work in OO terms.

User can have an Account property and that is a connection in OO terms, not by ID.
Same for Account - User property.

Order instance can have List OrderDetails property.

Look here for nice examples:
[EF Code First Cookbook — Recipe #4: Adding Details to a Master Entity](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2011/07/18/EFCodeFirtsRecipe04.aspx)

Comment: that is true, but if i were to add a new user, and then attach a account to them, I need to call savechanges to get an id for the user, so i can then use account.user_id = item.id

Comment: @Canvas If you use navigation properties, rather than foreign key properties, you wouldn't be needing that.

Comment: EF should be able to handle this automatically. Your multiple changes are added into UnitOfWork that is at SaveChanges sent to the database. At that point things like you said are sorted out. Yes, find your accountItem without using the id of the user.

Comment: @hvd indeed, that is my bad, I didn't not think of that :( bad database design on my side

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adeb3cf3-db49-40d2-99ae-c14b66fef1e3/rollback-and-commit-using-entity-framework?forum=adodotnetentityframework

The data is going to be saved to the database but not committed
until the Scope.Complete() is done.